# Is this the correct way to make 4 methods run at the same time async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Is this the correct way to make 4 methods run at the same time async?

```
Version 1:
    public void startup()
    {
        var aTask = Task.Run(async () => {
            Console.WriteLine(Fetchstuff1");
            var data3 = await GetStuff1();
        });

        var bTask = Task.Run(async  () => {
            Console.WriteLine("[Fetchstuff1stuff2");
            var data1= await GetStuff2();
        });

        var cTask = Task.Run(async () => {
            Console.WriteLine(Fetchstuff1stuff3");
            var data2 = GetStuff3();
        });


        Task.WaitAll(aTask, bTask, cTask);

        // DO STUFF AFTER ALL TASK OVER IS DONE
        var categories = GetCategories();
        var dt= CreateDatable();
        Sendtodatabase();
    }


    public async Task<string> Dostuff1,2,3()
    {
        try
        {

            using (HttpResponseMessage result = await _httpClient.GetAsync(Adrdess))
            using (HttpContent content = result.Content)
            {
                result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error"
        }
    }
```

Version 2:

```
public async Taskstartup()
    {
        await Task.WaitAll(lol());

        // DO STUFF AFTER ALL TASK OVER IS DONE
        var categories = GetCategories();
        var dt= CreateDatable();
        Sendtodatabase();
    }

    private async Task lol() {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Fetchstuff1");
            var data3 = await GetStuff1();
            Console.WriteLine("[Fetchstuff1stuff2");
            var data1= await GetStuff2();
            Console.WriteLine(Fetchstuff1stuff3");
            var data2 = GetStuff3();
        });
    }

    public async Task<string> Dostuff1,2,3()
    {
        try
        {

            using (HttpResponseMessage result = await _httpClient.GetAsync(Adrdess))
            using (HttpContent content = result.Content)
            {
                result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error"
        }
    }
```

version 3:

```
  public void startup()
    {
            Console.WriteLine(Fetchstuff1");
            var task1= GetStuff1();
            Console.WriteLine("[Fetchstuff1stuff2");
            var task2 = GetStuff2();
            Console.WriteLine(Fetchstuff1stuff3");
            var task3= GetStuff3();

        Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);

        List<String> data1 = await task1;
        List<String> data2 = await task2;
        List<String> data3 = await task3;
            // DO STUFF AFTER ALL TASK OVER IS DONE
            var categories = GetCategories();
            var dt= CreateDatable();
            Sendtodatabase();
        }


        public async Task<string> Dostuff1,2,3()
        {
            try
            {

                using (HttpResponseMessage result = await _httpClient.GetAsync(Adrdess))
                using (HttpContent content = result.Content)
                {
                    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }

                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error"
            }
        }
```

What I want to do is to make a,b,c task run at same time, since they only retrieves some data. Then I want the method to wait until all the task has returned, before it continue the function and do stuff after all the tasks is done.

Is this done correctly or could I do it in a more clean way? Should I use Async Task Startup()? I removed it because I had no functions with await from warning.
I then want all the last methods to run wait when it runs. because like sendtodatabase needs the dt from method executed before it.

In this situation my console application perform this: Main in Program.cs calls for startup method, startup call for datapoller method, datapoller call for handler method, and handler call for getstuff method. The method in the datapoller is an event,            Timer.Elapsed += DataPollerOnElapsed;
this can't be set to async... Which is in the midle of the hierchy.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `Task.WhenAll`?

Comment: Why are you using async/await when you start the task ? The task itself already run in the background, so you've nothing more with that, but you'll loose performance due to hidden work done by the framework (like keeping the context etc.). Your should replace by a return of the data, making your task typed.

Comment: @Fabske could you show me what you mean by correcting the code?
Some of the functions is using ReadFromDBAsync() in DoStuff1,2,3

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is this correct?” an off topic question, and what should I ask instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359466/why-is-is-this-correct-an-off-topic-question-and-what-should-i-ask-instead)

Comment: @FredrikLinger `aTask` and `bTask` just wrap a task in another CPU-bound task which should a) be avoided as you consume a precious threadpool thread which now can't be used by others, and b) it's in most cases unnecessary. It should just be `Console.WriteLine("Fetchstuff1"); var aTask = GetStuff1();` - the same for `bTask`.

Comment: @ckuri could you provide an example? With the CPU bound task?

Comment: @FredrikLinger That's what you are doing now. `Task.Run` creates a CPU-bound task by executing the provided action on a threadpool thread. This is usually only useful when your action isn't already a task, or when it is a non-CPU-bound task (i.e. it uses I/O async methods) but also contains complex/heavy calculations.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the Task.Run since you are just wrapping something that already returns a task.

```
public async Task StartupAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fetchstuff1");
    var aTask = GetStuff1Async();

    Console.WriteLine("Fetchstuff1stuff2");
    var bTask = GetStuff2Async();

    Console.WriteLine("Fetchstuff1stuff3");
    var cTask = GetStuff3Async();

    await Task.WhenAll(aTask, bTask, cTask);

    // DO STUFF AFTER ALL TASK OVER IS DONE
    var categories = GetCategories();
    var dt= CreateDatable();
    Sendtodatabase();
}
```

Comment: I want to remark that in OP's code only `GetStuff1` and `GetStuff2` seem to return a task, but not `GetStuff3`. Thus in the latter case the `Task.Run` may be necessary.

Comment: I'm gonna assume that is a typo amongst all the other typos (missing quotation marks, etc) since they are still calling that with async lambda.

Comment: The Getstuff1,2,3 returns data to a List. 

Could I do List<String> list = GetStuff1Async();?
Lets say if each function returns a list of strings that is bounded to a list<string> variable. How should I do this?

Comment: Can you look at version 3 and tell me if I've done it correctly?

In my case is that I got a console application, which is program.cs as a static void. What it does is that it calls on startup. I can't use async in the static void Main. How can I solve this? If there is least one function in a method that is async Task, then I should use async Task all the way up in the hierarchy?

Like Main calls for startup, startup call for datapoller, datapoller call for handler, and handler call for async getstuff.

Comment: @FredrikLinger You forgot to await the WhenAll in your version 3.

Comment: Ok, I've added await in my version 3, Does it looks correct now or should I do it different? Because I want to assign the data from the task to a list but I'm not sure if this is the right way and syntax to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The tasks will run asynchronously but your thread will block as `Task.WaitAll` blocks until all the tasks have been completed.

You should ideally change your startup method to be async (`public async Task startup()`) and the call to it should also be async, and the call to that etc. all the way up the hierarchy.

Then you can do `await Task.WhenAll(...)` which will non-blocking wait until the tasks have been completed.

Because you're using an async lambda, you're forcing the tasks to run in a different context. Which is a bit hacky.

Comment: What if I collect all under aTask and only use this Task.Run? When you say the task itself, does this refer to the method or task.run? @NibblyPig. I changed the void to async Task, and it say Code Severity Description Project File Line Suppression State
CS1998 Warning This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

How can I fix this?